# Entered text in TextField is not adding to a list

Tags: android, flutter

I'm creating an app where the user enters some text in Text Fields. There are 3 Text Fields. I want the input text that's being entered in the Text Fields to be stored in a list. I'm trying to to this by running the code below. But it always outputs an empty list. Can't seem to find the problem.

```
class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {

  List<String> items = [];
  var counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Create Your Need List', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),), backgroundColor: Colors.white, elevation: 0,),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 25, 15, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Add item'
              ),
              onChanged: (String str){
                setState(() {
                  items[counter] = str;
                  counter +=1;
                });
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Add item'
              ),
              onChanged: (String str){
                setState(() {
                  items[counter] = str;
                  counter +=1;
                });
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Add item'
              ),
              onChanged: (String str){
                setState(() {
                  items[counter] = str;
                  counter +=1;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, SlideFromLeft(widget: Dashboard()), ModalRoute.withName('/dashboard'));
      print(items);
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are directly adding the value at some index without defining the list size. Instead of that use `items.add(value)` to add-in the list and initialize items as `  List<String> items = List();
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not **adding** into the list.

You need change `items[counter] = str;` to

```
list.add(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you might want to  use List as dictionary. You also can do like that

```
  List<String> items = ['', '', ''];
```

rather than

```
  List<String> items = [];
```

just init an empty List. At the same time modify  counter +=1; to fixed index.